# Data has always changed(SQL Server Management Studio)

Tags: sql-server, concurrency

I am using SQL Server Management studio and keep getting the same error, and the only way to get rid of it(usually) is to reset the SQL server(which is very annoying, and sometimes impossible from my remote machine)

When I add a row to a table, and then I goto "Edit Top 200 Rows" it all displays and acts fine, and I go to a field I want to change. Then I change something like `0 -> 1` and then I get a nice friendly popup saying "Data has changed since the Results Pane was last retrieved... Optimistic Concurrency Control Error" If from here I say "Yes to commit changes to database anyway" I get "No row updated... The updated row has changed or been deleted since data was last retrieved"

It's a very annoying little thing, cause I don't like having to look up RIDs and then make an update statement(and possibly having to worry about escaping 's by hand)

Is there some way to turn this concurrency checking off or something? I know the row wasn't updated or anything, and I tried completely closing Sql Server Management Studio and reopening to no avail, and also tried refreshing the result pane, or refreshing the column view. Nothing gets rid of this error, but if I do a "update ... set ...=..." then it works, so I'm not really having any concurrency error..

Comment: Is this any table or one specific table? Does it have a timestamp/rowversion column?

Comment: No, it has neither of those columns, This tends to happen with some tables more than others(when one table is broken, others can still work though), but I would expect if I edited every table as much as this one, I would get the same thing for every table.

Comment: I found http://kbalertz.com/925719/receive-error-message-Server-Management-Studio-update-table-Server.aspx But this is 2008, and I have a primary/indexed key.

Comment: This seems to be the problem for me ... I have a [ in my text field and no primary key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqldatabaseengine/thread/7bf48a75-58a0-41d7-b514-b804a49ae8ff/

it seems to be a bug in SSMS I don't think I have over 4000 characters, but I can confirm this only happens on rows that have more data than others.. there seems to be some abritary limit that I can't quite put my finger on..

So, plainly SSMS is complete crap. I'll be looking for a new SQL manager..

Comment: LinqPad doesn't seem half bad.. for anyone else fed up with SSMS crap

Answer (score 5):

I had exactly the same problem. It looks like this article was pretty good at solving it. Seems all sorts of buggy things in some versions.

**See: [You may receive an error message when you try to use SQL Server Management Studio to update a row of a table in SQL Server 2005](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/925719/bug-you-may-receive-an-error-message-when-you-try-to-use-sql-server-ma).**

The table contains one or more columns of the text or ntext data type. The value of one of these columns contains the following characters.

- Percent sign (%)

  - Underscore (_)
  - Left bracket ([)
  - The table does not contain a primary key.

Comment: After removing the brackets I had in my data the concurrency issues went away. I'm using SSMS 2017 so I was surprised that such a small thing caused this problem. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: If it's not an option to change the content of the field (ie removing brackets etc because it contains json-data), I fixed it by excluding the affected column from the sql-statement. Then I can edit or delete the row without problems.

Answer (score -7):

You shouldn't edit a table directly from the table view.. you should use an UPDATE sql command.

Comment: I don't see why this is the accepted answer. The person is using SSMS and there are many reasons to do so. It's akin to someone asking about making a table with Microsoft Word and then you telling them to use LaTeX or Notepad.