# An Error Occurred Attempting To Delete Row 6 - SSMS 2014

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005, ssms, ssms-2014

> No Rows were deleted.
>
> A problem occurred attempting to delete row 6. Error Source:
>   Microsoft.sqlServer.Management.Data.Tools. Error Message: **The
>   updated rows has changed or been deleted since data was last
>   retrieved.**
>
> Correct the errors and attempt to delete the row again or press ESC to
>   cancel the changes(s).

Even my table consist the Primary Key and I don't know why this error occurs?

Taken the below SQL script by right clicking the table>>Script Table as>>Create To>>New Query for getting the structure of my table.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[FO_Entry](
    [Rec_Num] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [E_No] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [CA_Name] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [Created_On]  AS (getdate()),
    [App_1] [int] NULL CONSTRAINT [DF_FO_Entry_App_1]  DEFAULT ((0)),
    [App_2] [int] NULL CONSTRAINT [DF_FO_Entry_App_2]  DEFAULT ((0)),
    [App_3] [int] NULL CONSTRAINT [DF_FO_Entry_App_3]  DEFAULT ((0)),
    [App_4] [int] NULL CONSTRAINT [DF_FO_Entry_App_4]  DEFAULT ((0)),
    [Tot]  AS ((([App_1]+[App_2])+[App_3])+[App_4]) PERSISTED,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_FO_Entry] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Rec_Num] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Comment: Post  your delete command as well

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1457676/data-has-always-changedsql-server-management-studio

Comment: @TheGameiswar, Thanks for the reply. I am using Management Studio to view the table and after that I select a record and press CTRL+A to select all records and I press DELETE button to delete all the records.

Comment: if you could search stackoverflow,this seems a bug.You could do the same delete  via command

Comment: Is there any good website which can describe how to delete certain records using sql command because I am a newbie with sql syntaxes.

Comment: [Delete](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-za/library/ms189835.aspx)