# I get this error "Optimistic concurrency control error" when I want edit a SQL Server view

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables `table_1` and `Table_2`; I created this view in SQL Server:

```
SELECT dbo.Table_1.ID, dbo.Table_1.Title, dbo.Table_2.Descc
FROM dbo.Table_1 
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.Table_2 ON dbo.Table_1.ID = dbo.Table_2.ID
```

But when I want to enter data into `Descc` column, I get an error

> Optimistic concurrency control error

Comment: as per link suggested that you may enter more than 4000 character in your desc field: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1457676/data-has-always-changedsql-server-management-studio

Comment: i write only 5 character in desc field ...

Comment: please check this :- https://joshhighland.com/2010/02/03/sql-server-2008-fixed-data-has-changed-since-the-results-pane-was-last-retrieved/

Comment: not found in link,i tried timestamp,primarykey,special characters,no text, but not work

Comment: Please show the code for "entering data into descc".

Comment: @GordonLinoff code is here https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=a2e3b2c41488aa89b5bdec8a4d67a934

Answer (score 0):

```
This issue occurs if the following conditions are true:
The table contains one or more columns of the text or ntext data type.
The value of one of these columns contains the following characters:
Percent sign (%)
Underscore (_)
Left bracket ([)
The table does not contain a primary key.
Note This issue also occurs when you try to use Table Designer in Microsoft Visual Studio 2005 to update a table that is in a SQL Server 2005 database.
```

**Workaround**
To work around this issue, create a new query window in SQL Server Management Studio. Then, run a SQL UPDATE statement to update the row in the table.

Note If you receive the first error message that is mentioned in the "Symptoms" section, you can click Yes to update the row.
[microsoft link](https://support.microsoft.com/en-hk/help/925719/bug-you-may-receive-an-error-message-when-you-try-to-use-sql-server-ma)

Comment: i checked primary key and special characters like _ [ % and text type columns, every thing is okay but i get the error

Comment: @user11004309 did you embrace dbo.Table_2.Desc this like [dbo.Table_2.Desc]

Comment: Desc is a key word so if you want to use it as a column name in that case you have to use [Desc] otherwise it will throw error

Comment: @user11004309 can you please show me your effort https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=ef0863d54fd10034267322a028cd993d

Comment: cant run dbfiddle, Invalid object name 'dbo.Table_1'.

Comment: @user11004309 give me your link of fiddle

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=2cb2b20e7758d11bc4c0f75cdf04870f

Comment: @user11004309 you have to create both tables 1st then you can write query , i saw you just type your query but you have not created both tables

Comment: @abadin thuin i create both table but with error in dbfiddle view, https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=f291702cc9ba274e9116b5ef63896bad

Comment: @user11004309 https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=b5bcde2fe1ce40dd8a7f75936cdd78ec check this link it works fine

Comment: not work, table_2 is blank after update https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=a2e3b2c41488aa89b5bdec8a4d67a934